# Horizontally Aligning Bootstrap 3.3.5 Columns inside a row in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Re: Bootstrap 3.3.5 in Wordpress

I have not seen this issue before.  All I want to do is align 3 x .col-md-4 .wells inside a row, but they just won't align.  The first div is always a bit higher; see screenshot.

[image]

This is the code:

```
&nbsp; 

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 text-center">
       <a class="page-scroll" href="#how-to"><div class="home-plans well">
            <br/>
            <h2>1.</h2>
            <p class="lead text-left">Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo.p>
        </div> <!-- /well --></a>
    </div> <!-- /col-md-4 -->

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 text-center">
        <div class="home-plans well">
            <br />
            <h2>2.</h2>
             <p class="lead text-left">Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo.p>
        </div> <!-- /well -->
    </div> <!-- /col-md-4 -->

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 text-center">
        <div class="home-plans well">
            <br />
            <h2>3.</h2>
            <p class="lead text-left">Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo.</p>
        </div> <!-- /well -->
    </div> <!-- /col-md-4 -->
</div>
```

Using f12 tools in explorer, the issue seems to be the below CSS code styling the row:

```
/*media all*/
.btn-group-vertical > .btn-group::after, .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group::before, .btn-toolbar::after, .btn-toolbar::before, .clearfix::after, .clearfix::before, .container-fluid::after, .container-fluid::before, .container::after, .container::before, .dl-horizontal dd::after, .dl-horizontal dd::before, .form-horizontal .form-group::after, .form-horizontal .form-group::before, .modal-footer::after, .modal-footer::before, .nav::after, .nav::before, .navbar-collapse::after, .navbar-collapse::before, .navbar-header::after, .navbar-header::before, .navbar::after, .navbar::before, .pager::after, .pager::before, .panel-body::after, .panel-body::before, .row::after, .row::before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
```

This page is in Wordpress.  I have tried the same code in a normal HTML page and the .well .col-md-4s align OK.

To get the cols to align I can just remove the row, but I want to use rows.

This has been killing me for nearly one day now.  I have done loads of research and tried using clearfix and clear: both all over without joy.  Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Edit: I also note that the two rows in the footer section are causing the page footer to have a scroll bar?  So, I have had to remove those rows too.  It seems that I can't use rows in Wordpress with Bootstrap anymore for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it's really tricky to say without seeing more of the CSS but have you tried reformatting your first div as follows:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 text-center">
   <div class="home-plans well">
     <a class="page-scroll" href="#how-to">
        <br/>
        <h2>1.</h2>
        <p class="lead text-left">Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo.p>
      </a>
    </div> <!-- /well -->
</div> <!-- /col-md-4 -->
```

Then styling the inner anchor element as follows:

**CSS:**

```
.well > a {
    display: block;
}
```

I'd guess that it's something to do with the anchor element wrapping around the `.well` div?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I originally tried stripping out all the CSS just leaving Bootstrap.min.css for v3.3.5.  So, the bit of CSS I have seems not to effect this issue.  I removed the anchor, but no difference. Like I said above, if I remove the row like you have done the cols align, but I want the page in rows.  For the minute though, I have removed the rows to get everything how I want it, but it's not the solution I want.

Comment: @DaniB, Just to clarify, I'm not suggesting to remove the row, the above is just a snippet of the div I'm talking about... Keep everything else as is.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'll try again.

Comment: No difference unfortunately using display: block on .well > a